# "CSS Sprites" and background-repeat

Tags: css

is it possible to make [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) technique work well with background repeat? Thanks!c

Answer (score 2):

Generally not. It could be done if the repeating images:

- All repeat in only one direction
- All repeat in the same direction
- All the same width or height (depending on direction)
- Are as wide or tall (ditto) as the widest or tallest image in the collection

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with repeat-x & repeat-y, however you'll have to take this into consideration when designing your sprite.

For example you may have one sprite for general buttons, components, etc and another sprite for handling horizontal backgrounds.